# Integrating a few cxf, .Net, and Php based webservices using mule 3 esb

Tags: web-services, integration, esb, mule

I am a newbie in mule and ESB. We have couple of cxf based, .Net and PHP based
webservices. Currently we are communicating with each other using point to point
communication. As our webservices are increasing rapidly this type of communication
is getting cumbersome. We want to communicate with other webservicve endpoints using
ESB. We don't want to run our services inside Mule ESB. Here are our two sample
webservices -

http://someip:8991/abc/ws/Service1

http://someip:8992/def/ws/Service2

Could anyone please help me with the mule 3 based config for this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try out another Open Source ESB, here is an article from the [UltraESB users guide](http://adroitlogic.org/samples-articles-and-tutorials/15-tutorials/20-ultraesb-users-guide-the-helloesb-sample.html).

A proxy service created on the ESB can then proxy calls to your actual services, and your clients then invoke the endpoint exposed over the ESB instead. This prevents many point-to-point connections being made all across the enterprise. Now, using the ESB, you can mediate messages - maybe log accesses, save a copy to a DB, perform content based routing to decide if a "purchase-order" request should be sent to /POGoldVersion service or /POBronzeVesion or transform a "purchase-order-v1" request sent from an old client (using XSLT, XQuery, Smooks etc) before sending it to the new /POVersion2 service etc.